# Recyclerview + CardView OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview, clicklistener

I'm using `Recyclerview` for my datalist in `CardView`, but I don't know how to make onClick in my data list. Can someone help me to solve this?

My code is:

HomeFragment.Java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_grid_layout, container, false);
            dataList = view.findViewById(R.id.dataList);
            titles = new ArrayList<>();
            images = new ArrayList<>();
            titles.add("Berita");
            titles.add("Customer Care");
            titles.add("Cabang Clipan");
            titles.add("Info Layanan");
            titles.add("Info Pembayaran");
            titles.add("Promo");
            titles.add("Syarat Kedit");
            titles.add("Simulasi Kredit");
            images.add(R.drawable.ic_article);
            images.add(R.drawable.ic_cs);
            images.add(R.drawable.ic_cbng_clipan);
            images.add(R.drawable.ic_simulation);
            adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), titles, images);
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new 
            GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            dataList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            dataList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

I'm using `Adapter` for `Recyclerview`:

Adapter.Java

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer> images;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Adapter(Context ctx, List<String> titles,List<Integer> images){
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(titles.get(position));
        holder.gridIcon.setImageResource(images.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView gridIcon;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            gridIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Click on " + getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),SimulationActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(i.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have edited my adapter for `onClickListener`
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: That should be in RecyclerView `Adapter` can' you share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `OnClickListener` to the root item of the `ReyclerView` row which is `itemView` in your example.

You can do that optionally in the `ViewHolder` constructor or in `onBindViewHolder` method

Here it's in the `ViewHolder`

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView gridIcon;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        gridIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
        
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "My Item position: " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in the `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(titles.get(position));
    holder.gridIcon.setImageResource(images.get(position));
    
    
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "My Item position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, if you have a view such as a button in your cardview to which you wanna add the click listener, do it this way `holder.itemView.myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}`.

Comment: how if every item has one activity, because I try it, only one activity for all item

Comment: @OctavyantiPiliaElvinaPalopi I can't get your query.. can you elaborate more?

Comment: I guess she means, every itemView at different positions is supposed to perform a different action so the code within the listener should be different based on the itemView clicked.

Comment: I think so .. @OctavyantiPiliaElvinaPalopi can you tell what you want to do when an item is clicked .. I just added a `Toast` showing the item position so that clicking on a certain item will show its current position in the `RecyclerView` list

Comment: @MehranBehbahani yes i mean that

Comment: @everyone The OP should learn about how to pass data from an adapter to an activity using ```Intent```. This is similar to opening an "album or playlist" in a music player!

Comment: @Zain I have edited my Adapter, please tell me how to show the action for every itemView from my list